# Kotlin Volley request as global variable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

So I'm trying to get a phone number from a volley request to my server. I am then trying to send this number back to my server with a different volley request but the phone number appears as null when sent back despite the fact that I have saved the phone number into a variable in a separate kotlin class.

I guess I'm missing something but I cannot figure out how to save the response.getString("mobile") saved as a global variable that I can access for use outside of the var jor. Thanks for any help!!

```
var url_get_phone:String = url + "get_phone.php?username=" + UserInfo.name
var rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
var jor = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url_get_phone,
    null,Response.Listener{ response ->
       UserInfo.mobile = response.getString("mobile")
       Toast.makeText(this, "You want to share phone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       },
    Response.ErrorListener {  })
rq.add(jor)

var url_with_phone =  url + "add_details.php?" +
     "mobile=" + UserInfo.mobile +
     "&description=" + editTextTextMultiLine.text.toString() +
     "&username=" + UserInfo.name
var rq2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
var sr = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url_with_phone,
      Response.Listener { response ->
      Toast.makeText(this,"Details Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                },
      Response.ErrorListener {  })
rq2.add(sr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well I was able to solve my particular problem by just nesting the second request in the first after the UserInfo.mobile line. I am still curious how I would assign this as a global variable that I could use in a separate activity. Thanks!